# Argument error when concatenting string with variables in elixir

Tags: elixir, erlang-shell

Hi I am trying the [String Concatenation operatio](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/basics/#string-concatenation)n in [elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/). My code is as follows:

```
iex(1)> name="SHubham Agiwal"
        "SHubham Agiwal"
iex(2)> age =16
         16
iex(5)> "Hello" <> name <> "World" 
         "HelloSHubham AgiwalWorld"
iex(7)> "Hello" <> name <> "World" <>age
         ** (ArgumentError) argument error
```

As you can see, when I try to concat it with a single variable namely `name`, it gives me the output as `HelloSHubham AgiwalWorld`. But when I try to concat it with variables `name` and `age` I get `Argument error`. Can somebody let me know why I am getting this error?

Comment: Why do you expect _string concatenation_ to work with _integer_?

Comment: I have experience in java. So was thinking if we could concat integers to string like we do in java. Apparently we can't in elixir

Comment: @mudasobwa  can you post your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: The answer provided by @bitwalker is absolutely correct, why would I post my own? We do call the instance of string “binary” in Elixir, that is kinda Erlang’s legacy.

Comment: @shubhamagiwal92 I confess I'm not long on Java knowledge but don't you have to cast an integer to string before you concatenate it--even in Java?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci You can attach integer to a string directly. Try System.out.println("I am awesome"+6); It will give the output as "I am awesome6"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `age` is not a binary. You can use interpolation instead for this, like `"#{age}"`.

Comment: ...or `to_string(age)`, or `Integer.to_string(age)`.

Comment: @bitwalker You were right. The age is not binary. It is due to this that it is giving me a compile time error. using to_string solves the problem.